# android - upload new apk to prod - "unrequested" localisations added

Tags: android

I am faced with somewhat of a strange "issue":

Although I don't believe I made any actual changes that would warrant this, I was prompted with the fact that 56 new localisations were added to my latest APK.

This is obviously an error of some sort on my part, but I don't really know where to look...

What would cause this change?

I'm guessing it has to be manifest related...

I should note that I experimented with adding the google+ api through google API console, but did not bring about any changes to the actual apk I uploaded...
(I accidentally activated the translate API, but immediately disabled it; also, I deleted my API project prior to uploading my new APK...)

/e Screenshot: (Attention to the Localization line - used to be default, now it's default + 56 languages)

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this message from your Google Play Console?

Comment: Added the screenshot. So before under Localizations, I had only "default", now it's default + 56 languages

Comment: Did you add any language specific folders to your project? values-de, values-es, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added some new library in your project. E.g support library contains about 56 languages.

Comment: Upgraded from admob 6.4.1 to  google-play-services library, only change i can think of... Probably right! THANKS